# Is there any idiom in English for when something good happens, but you can’t be hopeful about it. Because it is temporary

Tags: phrase-requests

An idiom in English for when you can’t be hopeful about something good. Because it is temporary, better not be hopeful. Is there something like that?

Comment: Vaguely similar: *Don't wish your life away.*

Comment: Don't get your hopes up? Don't count yer chicks before they're hatched?

Comment: There's light at the end of the tunnel… but it's probably a train.

Comment: Needs clarification. Do you want a warning like "Don't count your chickens before they're hatched", or a description of someone who will never accept good things because they're too scared they will vanish (which might be a type of anxiety).